# Screen freezes after second screen is plugged in

Tags: multiple-monitors

The last days a very annoying problem has appeared on my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop. The laptop is an Asus UX32VD.

If I connect my second screen to the computer by VGA the screen seems to freeze. Both screens show the same image and the image seems to be a little part of what should have been on both screens. The screen is also frozen and it does not help to unplug the monitor. The only fix I have found is to restart the computer when this happends.

Does anyone have an idea about why this occurs? It worked fine until some days ago so I'll guess that there is some updated thing that is causing this. I have no idea of which software has been updated recently though.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing on Ubuntu 14.04 running on my Dell Vostro 3750.  I don't yet know how to fix it, but instead of restarting you can drop to a terminal, (`Ctrl-Alt-F1`) and then run `sudo stop lightdm` and `sudo start lightdm`.  This will just restart the X-server.  I'll update when I know more.